Help with late 90s/early 2000's cartoon (three characters, three is the magic number in theme song?)
It's been plaguing me for a while and I can't find out any information for the life of me.
Basically the show revolved around 2/3 main characters - young boys, animation style had them short but with stretched heads. Pretty sure the theme song had "three is the magic number" right at the end of it. Also pretty sure one of the main characters had blonde hair and wore a green sweater.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Do you remember what the plot was about? Any specific scene or episode?

This seems like it could be an episode of Schoolhouse Rock. According to the intro blurb from the attached YouTube video:

Debuted in 1973; the pilot episode of the series. Was written and sung by Bob Dorough.

Despite the 1973 debut I remember seeing these on public broadcast TV regularly in the 80's and 90's in the United States. 




Unfortunately this is not what it is and was pretty much the first result to come up on Google - I have attempted to search for it myself to no avail hence posting here

That particular song has never been featured on a TV show in that way. So it has to be something completely unrelated.
